# Generate HMAC-SHA256 hash with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, sha256, hmac

I need to generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash in a PCL (developing for Xamarin Forms) which doesn't support the .NET built-in HMAC/cryptography classes, so I'm working with BouncyCastle to implement my cryptography classes.

I need to generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash, but I haven't been able to find any example on Google, nor does BouncyCastle seem to have any documentation for this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# PCL HMACSHAX with BouncyCastle-PCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974846/c-sharp-pcl-hmacshax-with-bouncycastle-pcl)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974846/c-sharp-pcl-hmacshax-with-bouncycastle-pcl) I came up with this code:

```
public class HmacSha256
{
    public byte[] Hash(string text, string key)
    {
        var hmac = new HMac(new Sha256Digest());
        hmac.Init(new KeyParameter(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)));
        byte[] result = new byte[hmac.GetMacSize()];
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        hmac.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        hmac.DoFinal(result, 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Corresponding unit test (uses FluentAssertions):

```
[TestClass]
public class HmacSha256Tests
{
    private readonly HmacSha256 _hmac = new HmacSha256();

    [TestMethod]
    public void Hash_GeneratesValidHash_ForInput()
    {
        // Arrange
        string input = "hello";
        string key = "test";
        string expected = "F151EA24BDA91A18E89B8BB5793EF324B2A02133CCE15A28A719ACBD2E58A986";

        // Act
        byte[] output = _hmac.Hash(input, key);

        string outputHex = BitConverter.ToString(output).Replace("-", "").ToUpper();

        // Assert
        expected.Should().Be(outputHex);
    }
}
```

Comment: So where do `HMac` and `Sha256Digest` come from?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh see the OP/tags, those are BouncyCastle classes.

Comment: Tags are not class-specific they apply to the whole question, sometimes, at poster discretion, very tangentially. It's not uncommon for an answer to address the question but be unrelated to one or more question tags. By reading this piece of code, or, copying and pasting it to VS, one is still left to wonder what should be referenced for this to work. For example if you reference [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle-PCL) it DOES NOT work. Consequently, this answer could be improved by specifying exactly what assemblies/packages and namespaces should be referenced.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh fair enough, I don't know why your NuGet doesn't work. Maybe it's an old version? (since it's 1.0.0). I used Portable.BouncyCastle: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/.

Answer (score 2):

Using this PCL offshoot of BouncyCastle https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle-PCL/1.0.0.6 it's really easy, in fact identical to the windows api.

```
 public string ComputeHMAC(string message)
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.API_KEY);
        var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        byte[] result = hmac.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }
```

And a unit test using the actual .Net version:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Hash_Algorithm_Correct (
        [NoAutoProperties] HashMacService sut,
        string message)
    {
        string expected;

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.API_KEY);

        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
        {
            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            expected = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        var result = sut.ComputeHMAC(message);

        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
```

I was using PCLCrypto but it kept crashing on Xamarin iOS, this was much cleaner and could be unit tested, wheras PCLCrypto required the platform apis so had to be deployed to a device.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void CreateToken(string message, string key)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[]keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);


        HMACSHA256 hmacsha = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);
        byte[]messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);

        byte[]hashmessage = hmacsha.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(ByteToString(hashmessage));
    }
    public static string ByteToString(byte[]buff) {
        string sbinary = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++) {
            sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); // hex format
        }
        return (sbinary);
    }
```

Above code saved my time while working for HMAC-SHA256, I hope this may help someone and here is the reference in detail http://billatnapier.com/security01.aspx